# Error Printing: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have a VB WinForms app that prints PDFs using Process.Start, and it has been working fine for ages on Windows 10.  Today I go to use it and get the following error message:

"No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"

Nothing has changed to cause this, I have not changed PDF Viewer or uninstalled anything.  I can open a PDF by double clicking on it no problems.

I wrote a small console app to replicate the issue and prove this had nothing to do with the WinForms app:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim pi As New Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Dim url As String = "C:\PathToPDF\.pdf"
    pi.FileName = url
    pi.Verb = "PrintTo"
    pi.CreateNoWindow = True
    pi.Arguments = """Microsoft Print to PDF"""
    pi.UseShellExecute = True

    Console.WriteLine(url)

    Diagnostics.Process.Start(pi)

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

The above program replicates the error.  I have verified that the file exists and is accessible and tried it with double slashes and single slashes, they give the same error:

"No application is associated with the specified file for this operation".

The same application is working fine on other PCs in the office.
Has anyone else had this happen, and if so how did they fix it?
My PDF viewer is PDFXChange Viewer, and it has been working fine PDFs printed using this method for years.  I have not updated the program, and it says in the about page that the last installed updated was in 2016.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried printing a PDF from File Explorer on that machine? The verb you're using is equivalent to right-clicking the file and selecting the corresponding command. If that doesn't work either, or there is no such command, then that indicates a Windows issue and your app is behaving exactly as it should. It may just be that the relevant file association has been lost on that machine for some reason. In fact, that is the most obvious reason this could happen.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, I had the same issue. Maybe you can try it in a slightly other way. I have this in my application and it works fine:

```
    Dim myp As New Process
    myp.StartInfo.FileName = filename 'Full path to pdf
    myp.Start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this produced the exact same outcome for me.